# Property 'compSelected' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

[In my angular component app I get error property in this "compSelected, userSelected" .I dont know what to do with it...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT9U4.png)

Comment: Instead of image post the question as text and be specific to the problem.

Comment: yeah Sure Mr.Jai and Thanks for that...!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `!` to the end of the property declaration like:

```
compSelected!: typeOfYour;
//          ^-----check this
```

---

`!`: *[definite assignment assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#--strictpropertyinitialization)*